# Why do we use the terms "non-increasing/non-decreasing/non-negative"?

Tags: functions, terminology

I am not sure if I have to ask my question here. But I will try and thank you in advance.

Why some authors (in books or in papers) use the following terms:

- Function $f$ is **non-increasing**;
- Function $f$ is **non-decreasing**;
- A number $a$ is **non-negative**;
- $\cdots$.

Why they do not simply say:

- $f$ is **decreasing**?
- $f$ is **increasing**?
- $a$ is **positive**?

Is there a difference between these terms?

Thank you very much for you time and help.

Comment: $f$ may be constant, $f$ may be constant, $a$ may be zero respectively.

Comment: The difference is between $x < y \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(y)$ or $x<y \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y)$. For instance, the constant function is non-increasing, but it is not decreasing.

Comment: It's also good to be aware that the terminology varies. In English, it's usually "nonnegative"/"positive" and "nondecreasing"/"increasing", whereas in some other languages they instead use (their counterpart of) "positive"/"strictly positive" and "increasing"/"strictly increasing".

Comment: (And in Swedish we use "nonnegative"/"positive" and "increasing"/"strictly increasing", confusingly enough...)